# What's the meaning of "a side flash" in the context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I came across the sentence:

> This comment is 10,000 times more jarring and disrespectful and creepy and gross than a side flash.

[The source](https://www.yahoo.com/style/chrissy-teigen-trolls-guy-trolled-met-gala-look-205441120.html)

I can not find anything useful after an extensive search on the web.

So, what's the meaning of "a side flash" in the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly won't find "side flash" anywhere in the Urban Dictionary. Ms. Teigen invented the term, but most native English speakers would understand her personal slang from context. She is referring to her own "wardrobe malfunction" described in this article:

https://www.yahoo.com/style/chrissy-teigen-apologises-for-major-wardrobe-malfunction-in-the-best-way-095122902.html

To "flash" someone is to show your naked body to that person in a surprising way. Perverted men sometimes do it to women on the street. Sometimes women do it by baring their breasts at Mardi Gras. As the article so delicately puts it, Ms. Teigen flashed her "hoohah" by wearing an overly revealing dress.

So when she refers to her own "side flash," she is merely saying that she flashed all the photographers who were taking side photos of her. She is saying that the person who wrote that crude tweet is many times more crude than her showing her hoohah -- which is a debatable point, in my opinion.

Comment: So, what's the 'hoohah'?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hooha

Comment: as I asked to Andrew: 
I am also curious about the usage of flash as a verb here. Does this sentence make sense？ “She flashed her boobs in the public.” Looks like the object is body part, not a person. Any opinions?

Comment: You can flash your boobs, yes, or you can also flash someone.  For example, a lady from the Victorian era could have flashed the groundskeeper by showing a little bit of ankle. How ribald!

Answer (score 1):

To "flash" someone means to either deliberately or inadvertently show any part of your body that is ordinarily expected to be kept covered in that venue.  It doesn't have to be genitalia, as we can talk about "flashing" an ankle or knee in countries where women don't ordinarily show those body parts.

In other words, "flashing" needs to be unexpected.  You can't *flash* someone at a nude beach, for example, because it's a place where you expect to see naked people.

In this context, while entering the American Music Awards, Teigen *flashed* her *mons pubis* (the area above her genitalia) to a photographer standing to one *side* of her.  Thus "side flash".

Comment: I am also curious about the usage of flash as a verb here. Does this sentence make sense？ “She flashed her boobs in the public.” Looks like the object is body part, not a person. Any opinions?

Comment: @dan  Yes, you can say someone *flashed* a body part, or just leave it unspecified "she flashed the waiting photographers"